# How to place variables in IAR compiler in specific order?

Tags: c, linker, iar, linker-flags

I'm trying to place some variables into a specific ROM lication.

In linker configuration file:

```
define symbol __ICFEDIT_region_APP_ROM_start__  = 0x08070000 ;
define symbol __ICFEDIT_region_APP_ROM_end__    = 0x0807FFFF;

define region APP_ROM_region   = mem:[from __ICFEDIT_region_APP_ROM_start__   to __ICFEDIT_region_APP_ROM_end__];

place in APP_ROM_region { readonly section test_data};
```

In source file:

```
#pragma default_variable_attributes = @ "test_data"

const U8 testVar8 = 0;
const U8 testArray512[512];
const uint32_t testVar32 = 0x1234ABCD;
const U8 testArray500[500];

#pragma default_variable_attributes =
```

Generated .map file:

```
test_data           const    0x08070000   0x200  source_file.o [1]
test_data           const    0x08070200   0x1f4  source_file.o [1]
test_data           const    0x080703f4     0x4  source_file.o [1]
test_data           const    0x080703f8     0x1  source_file.o [1]
```

```
testArray512            0x08070000   0x200  Data  Gb  source_file.o [1]
testArray500            0x08070200   0x1f4  Data  Gb  source_file.o [1]
testVar32               0x080703f4     0x4  Data  Gb  source_file.o [1]
testVar8                0x080703f8     0x1  Data  Gb  source_file.o [1]
```

At all it works - the variables are in the correct section.

But linker has put it in order due to variables' size.

Is there a way to tell linker not to change the order of variables, so they will appear in map file in the same order as they're declared in source file?

The goal is:

```
testArray8              0x08070000     0x1  Data  Gb  source_file.o [1]
testArray512            0x08070001   0x200  Data  Gb  source_file.o [1]
testVar32               0x08070201     0x4  Data  Gb  source_file.o [1]
testVar500              0x08070205   0x1f4  Data  Gb  source_file.o [1]
```

Comment: Wouldn't it be simpler to just use `struct`?

Comment: @KamilCuk, unfortunately, not at all. This file will be generated outside the project, so its appearence is fixed. It consists of strings: "type name initial_value". And in case of using struct the initial_values should be set separately from the declaration.

Comment: C compilers and linkers are free to sort like they wish. You might get to know how yours work, and try to force a specific order. However, the C standard defines a sequence only for `struct`s. -- A linker is quite smart to place the biggest object first to find some good solution. It may or may not have an option to change this behaviour. Did you read all of its manual? And did you ask IAR who provided the tool?

Comment: @thebusybee, thank you for the answer! Yes I've looked through full official IAR guide pdf and found no suitable solution. I'll also try to get an answer from IAR support, but it would be perfect if I could find the fast solution or advice here :)

Comment: Well, I didn't answer really, just gave hints. ;-) But, if the manuals don't reveal any option, I'm afraid that there is none. You might like to fall back to assembler to get what you want.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way to tell linker not to change the order of variables, so they will appear in map file in the same order as they're declared in source file?

I am not aware of an *option* that forces the linker to respect the variable order in the source file.
But there is an way to reach your goal using the `block` directive in the linker configuration file.

The [IAR C/C++ Development Guide](https://www.iar.com/support/user-guides/user-guide-iar-embedded-workbench-for-arm/) states for the `place in` directive:

> The `place in` directive places sections and blocks in a specific region.
>   The sections and blocks will be placed in the region in an arbitrary order.
>   To specify a specific order, use the `block` directive.

Thus, in the source file each of the variables needs to go into a separate section:

```
const U8       testVar8          @ test_data_1 = 0;
const U8       testArray512[512] @ test_data_2;
const uint32_t testVar32         @ test_data_3 = 0x1234ABCD;
const U8       testArray500[500] @ test_data_4;
```

In the linker configuration file we add a `block` definition with the `test_data_*` sections in desired order and place it at the beginning of the target region:

```
define symbol __ICFEDIT_region_APP_ROM_start__  = 0x08070000 ;
define symbol __ICFEDIT_region_APP_ROM_end__    = 0x0807FFFF;

define region APP_ROM_region   = mem:[from __ICFEDIT_region_APP_ROM_start__   to __ICFEDIT_region_APP_ROM_end__];

define block TEST_DATA with fixed order { 
  readonly section test_data_1,
  readonly section test_data_2,
  readonly section test_data_3,
  readonly section test_data_4
};

place at start of APP_ROM_region { block TEST_DATA };
```